# Using month qualification in SUMIFS statment

Tags: excel, excel-2007, sumifs

Here's what I'm looking for....
Trying to Sum the count of worksheet 'Results 2013' column G items

```
IF Cell A matches "Canada"
IF Cell E (date) is July
```

Having trouble with the date portion of the SUMIFS statement below.

```
SUMIFS('Results 2013'!$G$2:$G$510,'Results 2013'!$A2:$A$510
    ,"=Canada",'Results 2013'!$E2:$E510,MONTH('Results 2013'!$E2:$E510)=7)
```

Example value of "Results 2013"$E$480 is

I try this formula, and it provides back "January" which is obviously incorrect.

```
=TEXT(MONTH('Results 2013'!$E$480),"mmmm")
```

However, this formula, results in TRUE or 1

```
=IF(MONTH('Results 2013'!$E$480)=7,1,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to add a column `Month` using the `MONTH` function to compute values, and then refer to this new column in `SUMIFS`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an array formula , then you can use month on the entire column:

```
{SUM(if('Results 2013'!$A2:$A$510="Canada",1,0)*if(MONTH('Results 2013'!$E2:$E510)=7,'Results 2013'!$G$2:$G$510,0))}
```

just remember to use ctrl+shift+enter rather than the usual enter to finish the formula

Answer (score 1):

This tests whether the date values in column E fall within the range 7/1/2013 and 7/31/2013. If your dates all fall within 2013, it will work.

```
SUMIFS('Results 2013'!$G$2:$G$510,'Results 2013'!$A2:$A$510,"=Canada",
       'Results 2013'!$E2:$E510,">="&DATE(2013,7,1),
       'Results 2013'!$E2:$E510,"<="&DATE(2013,7,31))
```

This array formula will work with the more general case of dates falling within any year:

```
=SUM(G2:G510*(A2:A510="Canada")*(MONTH(E2:E510)=7))
```